# ADA compliance Online tool

Tags: html

Can anyone please provide me link to validate my site is ADA compliance or not

Can anyone please provide me link to validate my site is ADA compliance or not

Comment: Please have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

One of the way for doing ADA testing: 
Pass your URL in [Site for Testing](http://wave.webaim.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I've used wave's chrome extension for a few years & I like it.

A few days ago I found [aXe](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/axe/lhdoppojpmngadmnindnejefpokejbdd), and I like that chrome extnesion more.